# Most efficient way to get the latest version of an rpm via web

Tags: linux, bash, wget

This is my attempt using wget to pull down the web page, dig for latest tar file and rerun a wget to take it down. In the example, i'm taking down pip.

```
wget https://pypi.org/project/pip/#files
wget $(grep tar.gz index.html | head -1 | awk -F= '{print $2}' | sed 's/>//' | sed 's/\"//g')
gunzip -c $(ls | grep tar  |tail -1) | tar xvf -
yum install -y python-setuptools
cd $(ls -d */ | grep pip)
python setup.py install
cd ..
```

I'm sure that there is a better way, perhaps only using one wget or similar

Comment: how about using the package manager to handle the version and the upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like that?

```
wget $(curl -s "https://pypi.org/project/pip/#files"|grep -o 'https://[^"]*tar\.gz')
```